# Capturing multiple pictures with CameraCaptureUI in VB

Tags: vb.net, camera, capture

I'm writing an app that will take multiple photos that will later be renamed and moved. The first step I'm stuck on is bringing up the camera itself. When I try to create the `CameraCaptureUI` class, it just generates a blank class that does not do anything.

I have searched through the Microsoft CameraCaptureUI documentation but I can only get it to open using their code, and nothing I have tried works so far.

I just want the ccui to pop out when the user selects a start button.

Answer (score 0):

This Worked for me.

```
var capture = new CameraCaptureUI();
        capture.PhotoSettings.Format = CameraCaptureUIPhotoFormat.Jpeg;
        capture.PhotoSettings.MaxResolution = CameraCaptureUIMaxPhotoResolution.HighestAvailable;

        var result = await capture.CaptureFileAsync(CameraCaptureUIMode.Photo);
        if (result == null) return null;
var copy = await result.CopyAsync(KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary, fileNameNoEx + result.FileType, NameCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);
                aPath = copy.Path;
```